# How can I close a open Print window in cypress using javascript function

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I close a `print window` open during on click of a print button in cypress. I am calling a `js` function to close the window and its not performing the close, could someone please advise on how to resolve the problem ?

```
context('Print button tests', () => {
  it.only('Verify the display of Print and close the window', () => {
    cy.get('.timetable-filter-panel-button.btn.btn-primary > span')
      .contains("Print current view")
      .click();
    printClose();    
  })
})
```

//Javascript function to close the open window:

```
function printClose(){
    window.close(); 
}
```

Comment: @bkucera Can you please help with the above question ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't, same as you can't operate on [other browser dialogs](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2118)

Comment: Found this https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/894, the only solution seems to be something like this.

Comment: But I saw that solution, I want to close the print dialog after opening.

Comment: @soccerway maybe I'm a bit late, but I got the same issue & I solved with the code snippet posted below. I hope it helps!

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Did you get solution to above problem ?

Comment: Yes, I just reshared the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test the print popup with Cypress like so:

```
it('Print button renders & opens modal', () => {
  // Clicks & asserts the button that triggers the popup window to print
  cy.get('[data-test="button-print"]')
    .should('exist')
    .and('be.visible')
    .click();

  // Assert printing was called once
  cy.visit('/inner.html', {
    onBeforeLoad: win => {
      cy.stub(win, 'print');
    },
  });

  cy.window().then(win => {
    win.print();
    expect(win.print).to.be.calledOnce;

    // this line closes the print popup
    cy.document().type({ esc });
  });
});
```

Comment: Does it works for you? I don't think that it works (at least on my side). Your suggestion is to work with print window (which is an OS system window but not browser window) in the same way as with browser popup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example by using stub. Works in cypress v10.

What it does is call the stubbed `window.print()` function, instead of opening the real dialogue and then trying to close it.

Because you just want to test if the print button will call `window.print()`. This test should be enough.

Also, this will work across browsers and OSs.

```
describe('Test print', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-07-14/canada-raises-rates-1-percentage-point-could-australia-follow/101239294', {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        // Stub window.print functions here
        cy.stub(win, 'print')
      },
    })

  })

  it('click print button should call the print dialog', () => {
    cy.get('button._1KwgR._22AuU').click()
    cy.get('button._1KwgR.vGCs_._2-5J1').click()
    cy.window().its('print').should('be.called')
  })
})
```